# Determine Cluster Label in K-means

Tags: cluster, data-mining

I have dataset that is contain 150 data that is actually divided into 3 group. Each group has it’s own label.

I do clustering process with K-means algorithm to group the data.

I need to assign the label of each group that is created by K-means process. So I could compare the result of K-means with the data training.

Anybody could help to explain how to determine the label of each group?

Comment: **[cross-posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is strictly frowned upon...'")** at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826407/determine-cluster-label-in-k-means

Answer (score 0):

arbitrarily choose the label for each group and check the result with each of the 3! permutations

or if the label relate to the relative location you can use that, `N` is assigned to the group with the highest y coordinate and so on

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have no idea how to implement your explanation into code. May I ask you to write the algorithm so I could interpret it into code?

Comment: There are smarter solutions than trying permutations...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse you are welcome to describe them in another answer,

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. See the Wikipedia article on cluster analysis for *widely accepted* measures of evaluating clusters, such as the **adjusted rand index**.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [cluster evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Evaluation_and_assessment) in Wikipedia.

No clustering algorithm will assign a label such as `iris_setosa` to the cluster, unless you provide the labels to the clustering algorithm somehow (but then it is no longer clustering, actually, but classification).

So you will only have `first_cluster`, `second_cluster`, `third_cluster` type of labels.

There are various measures proposed to compare the *structure* of the clusters in comparison to the original data set. But **usually there will not be a 1:1 correspondence** to the original labels.